# "However" used in a conditional clause?

Tags: grammar, clauses

Example: However, I would be able to transfer the money if you would give me your bank account number.

Is it grammatically correct to use adverbs such as "however" in a conditional clause? I personally think it sounds off but I thought I may ask first before making my mind up. I haven't found any articles related to this subject either.

Comment: ***however*** and the conditional bear no intrinsic relationship to each other.

Comment: Could you put a clause before the however, now you have read the answers?

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt provide enough context in my question.                 Here's the sentence:      I couldn't transfer the money due to the fact that my bank doesn't allow foreign currency on their normal credit cards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***However*** is a marker of *contrast*, carrying the sense of "despite that" ([see Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/however)).

This is a perfectly normal way to use it, provided that it is a statement that follows another, with a meaning that makes *however* appropriate. It doesn't matter whether it's conditional.

Answer (score 7):

*However* is fine if you introduce a statement that is going to contradict something you've said before.

I am worried about your if-clause, though.

> However, I would be able to transfer the money if you **gave** me your bank account number.

Comment: From what I know the "if+ would" construction is usable when making a polite request.

Comment: Yes, it's often used in that way, in my experience.

Comment: Yes, OMG, that if clause. Admittedly, with many financial institutions, that is the requirement for the procedure known as the "transfer".